# How can I satisfy '(int) => void' is not a subtype of type '((num) => void)?' exception?

Tags: flutter, dart, callback, sharedpreferences, nullable

I'm using [pref](https://pub.dev/packages/pref) plugin in my Flutter project. I have two slider settings for configure a lower limit and an upper limit. I'd like prevent the user to configure an invalid combination setting when the lower limit would be larger than the upper or the other way around.

The `PrefSlider` doesn't have a validate method unfortunately, so I'm trying to put out the fire after the fact in an onChanged handler:

```
      PrefSlider<int>(
        title: "Lower Limit",
        pref: "lower_limit",
        trailing: (num value) => Text("$value"),
        min: 0,
        max: 300,
        onChange: (value) {
          final upperLimit = PrefService.of(context).get<int>("upper_limit") ?? 300;
          if (value >= upperLimit) {
            PrefService.of(context).set<int>("lower_limit", upperLimit - 1);
          }
        },
      ),
      PrefSlider<int>(
        title: "Upper Limit",
        pref: "upper_limit",
        trailing: (num value) => Text("$value"),
        min: 0,
        max: 300,
        onChange: (value) {
          final lowerLimit = PrefService.of(context).get<int>("lower_limit") ?? 0;
          if (value <= lowerLimit) {
            PrefService.of(context).set<int>("upper_limit", lowerLimit + 1);
          }
        },
      ),
```

When I move the slider and the [pref](https://pub.dev/packages/pref) tries to call my onChanged function I get a big fat exception:

```
E/flutter (21583): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type '(int) => void' is not a subtype of type '((num) => void)?'
E/flutter (21583): #0      _PrefSliderState._onChange (package:pref/src/slider.dart:90:18)
E/flutter (21583): #1      _SliderState._handleChanged (package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart:540:24)
E/flutter (21583): #2      _RenderSlider._startInteraction (package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart:1235:17)
E/flutter (21583): #3      _RenderSlider._handleTapDown (package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart:1296:5)
E/flutter (21583): #4      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapDown.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:580:61)
E/flutter (21583): #5      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (21583): #6      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapDown (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:580:11)
E/flutter (21583): #7      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkDown (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:287:5)
E/flutter (21583): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.didExceedDeadline (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:258:5)
E/flutter (21583): #9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.didExceedDeadlineWithEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:501:5)
E/flutter (21583): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.addAllowedPointer.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:454:41)
E/flutter (21583): #11     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1346:47)
E/flutter (21583): #12     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
E/flutter (21583): #13     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1162:7)
E/flutter (21583): #14     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1202:23)
E/flutter (21583): #15     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1354:13)
E/flutter (21583): #16     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1258:19)
E/flutter (21583): #17     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1186:23)
E/flutter (21583): #18     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
E/flutter (21583): #19     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:395:19)
E/flutter (21583): #20     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:426:5)
E/flutter (21583): #21     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
```

And I just cannot figure out what's wrong. Somehow the handler function should be nullable? What's that question mark in `'((num) => void)?'`? Here is the code section where the plugin tries to call my handler:

```
  Future<void> _onChange(double value) async {
    final service = PrefService.of(context, listen: false);

    if (T == double) {
      service.set<double>(widget.pref, value);

      if (widget.onChange != null) {
        widget.onChange!(value);
      }
    } else if (T == int) { // for PrefSlider<int>
      service.set<int>(widget.pref, value.round());

      if (widget.onChange != null) {
        widget.onChange!(value.round()); // <- this is the call
      }
    } else if (T == num) {
      service.set<double>(widget.pref, value);

      if (widget.onChange != null) {
        widget.onChange!(value);
      }
    }
  }
```

To view at the broader picture I was thinking that maybe I could convert the `min` and `max` fields to states and somehow rebuild with each change, but that would probably break the UI.

Comment: The error means that it expects a function that takes a `num` argument and returns nothing (and the function itself could be `null`), but you instead passed a function that takes an `int` argument.  That's not allowed since the callback might called with, say, a `double`, which a `void Function(int)` would not expect.  However, I can't explain *why* you're getting that error (`PrefSlider<T>`'s `onChange` is `void Function(T)`, and you explicitly specify `int` for `T`).

Comment: Furthermore, `widget.onChange!(value.round())` seems wrong since it would need to be `widget.onChange!(value.round() as T)` (and that's the error *I* get when I try a distilled example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I could sooth the exception by specifying explicit `num` type for the callback:

```
  PrefSlider<int>(
    title: "Lower Limit",
    pref: "lower_limit",
    trailing: (num value) => Text("$value"),
    min: 0,
    max: 300,
    onChange: (num value) {
      final upperLimit = PrefService.of(context).get<int>("upper_limit") ?? 300;
      if (value >= upperLimit) {
        PrefService.of(context).set<int>("lower_limit", upperLimit - 1);
      }
    },
  ),
  PrefSlider<int>(
    title: "Upper Limit",
    pref: "upper_limit",
    trailing: (num value) => Text("$value"),
    min: 0,
    max: 300,
    onChange: (num value) {
      final lowerLimit = PrefService.of(context).get<int>("lower_limit") ?? 0;
      if (value <= lowerLimit) {
        PrefService.of(context).set<int>("upper_limit", lowerLimit + 1);
      }
    },
  ),
```

It's interesting that these are all run-time only exceptions and it also happens if I'd remove the explicit `num` from the `trailing: (num value) => Text("$value"),`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the generic type into `num` instead of `int`

```
PrefSlider<num>
```

Comment: That may solve the exception, however this would result in branching onto a `service.set<double>` code instead of a `service.set<int>` just like if it was a `PrefSlider<double>`.